# This regular expression throws an error in JavaScript: <li id=\"[^\"]*+\"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of LI elements for which I need to change the ID names of.

Example target text I would search:

```
<li id="apple">blah blah blah</li>
<other stuff>
<li id="bacon">blah blah blah</li>
```

I would want to find just the part that says:

```
<li id="idnamehere"
```

I tried using this line of code in JavaScript:

```
myRegExp = new RegExp('<li id="[^"]*+"', "g");
```

However I get this error:

```
"SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: nothing to repeat"
```

When I try this expression in a regular expression editor, it works fine. Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: What do you think `*+` means?

Comment: Why in the world would you SEARCH for something when you can just use the DOM?

Comment: (in response to Incognito) I'm duplicating a known element, and all of it's children. For the duplicated items, I want to only change the IDs. If I  duplicate them first via DOM, then I'll already have conflicting items with the same IDs. If there is a better way, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no entity for the `+` to repeat. decide if you want to use `+` or `*`, i.e. (i removed the escapes)

```
<li id="[^"]+"
```

to match one-or-more-character-ids or

```
<li id="[^"]*"
```

to match empty id, too. furthermore you don’t need explicit lazy or greedy matching if you use the unambiguous way you did: `*?` and `*` mean the same in your case, i.e. “match everything until you encounter an quotation mark.”

but generally: don’t parse XML with regular expressions, as the XML parsers built in your browser normally do a better job than you.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript doesn't support [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), therefore `[^"]*+` is illegal. Drop the `+`, then it should work.

Comment: Or the `*` if you don't want to allow `id=""`. But this is correct, especially for mentioning possessive quantifiers. +1